# How to install Rdio App on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: software-installation, 15.04, rdio

Following the instructions mentioned [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/install-rdio-app-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04-linux-mint/), I realized that no packages are available to 15.04.

After adding repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sgringwe/rdio
```

The update process (`sudo apt-get update`) failed with:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sgringwe/rdio/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Does it is possible to install Rdio in 15.04?

Comment: If there are no packages for your current ubuntu release, then contact with the maintainer of the Third Party Repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
sudo apt-get install debhelper
sudo apt-get install valac-0.18
sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-dev
sudo apt-get install libdbusmenu-glib-dev
sudo apt-get install libdbusmenu-gtk3-dev
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libnotify-dev
sudo apt-get install libindicate-dev
sudo apt-get install libunity-dev
sudo apt-get install libsoup2.4-dev
sudo apt-get install libjson-glib-dev
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev
```

Compile with these steps:

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/sgringwe/rdio.git
cd rdio
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
make
```

Install the application with:

- The classic way `make install`:

  ```
  sudo make install
  ```

### OR

- Create a `deb` package and install

  ```
  sudo apt-get install checkinstall
  sudo checkinstall
  ```

Comment: `cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr` does not work and, instead, you need to remove the two dots `..` that currently move you up one folder level. A correct approach would be ``cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr``

Comment: I tried to edit just this, but AskUbuntu does not accept editions with less that 6 characters changed. That is the reason I edited the `apt-get install` lines, but the important thing is the deletion of the two dots `..`

Comment: Sure? I have tested it with the two dots and it works. o_O

Comment: @PauloCoghi give me a second. I'am on mobile. I will check it.

Comment: The two dots returns one level in folder, exiting `rdio` and making `cmake` doesn't finding the necessary files

Comment: @PauloCoghi I had forgotten two commands, sorry.

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thanks for your contribution!!